# Redefinition of C++ classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, redefinition

I have this code which I CANNOT change:

A.h

```
 class B;
 class A
{
  A();
  void * getB();
  private:
  B * b;
}
```

A.cxx

```
namespace
{
    class B : public QTabWidget
    {
        foo()
        {
         ...
        }
        bar()
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}
A::A()
{
    b = new B();
}
A::getB()
{
    return b;
}
```

I want to access b and it's methods (foo or bar or inherited methods ) in a class which inherits A.
Can I do that?

C.h

```
class C : public A
{
  C();
  private:
  D * d;
}
```

C.cxx

```
namespace
{
    class D : public QTabWidget //Exact copy of class B
    {
        foo()
        {
        ... 
        }
        bar()
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
C::C()
{
    d = (D*) getB();
    d.foo()
    d.bar()
}
```

Is it safe? Is it allowed? I've tried it and it seems to work.
If it is safe, can I extend D with more static methods, or Methods, or even attributes?

Comment: From compiler point of view this will work because it's a simple copy to `D` type. But, from point of designing I don't know if it's allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not safe.

In theory, you may be able to make it work, as long as the first part of `D` is identical to `B`. You could probably append new things to `D` as well.

In practice though, it's usually a *very* bad idea. You're relying on manually keeping the classes in sync with each other. More importantly, you're relying on the compiler handling both classes in exactly the same way, which may depend on various configuration options (e.g. packing).

If you make the slightest mistake then you will get undefined behaviour, because the program could end up accessing or executing something arbitrary. Crucially, it might **seem** to work for a while, and then suddenly break unexpectedly in any number of ways. That kind of problem can be very hard to track down because you're deliberately bypassing the compiler's type checking.

Comment: Well what could i do? i need access to this class.
I also can include A.cxx in C.cxx, but i get a warning :
 warning: ‘..’ has a field ‘...’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace .

is it a better idea ?

Comment: I agree about the "syncing class" part. But considering there is not attribute at all in this duplicated class, can it really break anytime ?
If i call d.foo(), wich binary code is executed? the one produced from B ou D ?

Comment: If class `B` has no attributes then why do the functions need to be member methods? You could just declare them as global functions and call them directly, ignoring the object.

Comment: i can't modify anything in class B. and actually B has no attributes on it's own, however it has inherited attributes, wich i need to access.

Comment: In that case, the best you can do is `reinterpret_cast` the pointer to the base class type. It's not ideal, and you won't be able to access any of its protected members. However, since you're casting the pointer to a type that's legitimately in its inheritance hierarchy, it should be safe. (For additional safety, you'd normally want to use `dynamic_cast` for situations like this. However, that's not possible because the `B` declaration is hidden.)

Comment: I'm afraid it will not be enough, since i need to access foo and bar.
What about including the .cxx ?

Comment: You should never include a source file unless you really know what you're doing. It can result in the same code being compiled in two separate translation units, which will cause some major linker problems. Unfortunately what you're wanting to do is simply not possible. The whole point of declaring a class in a source file (especially inside an unnamed namespace) is to **prevent** access to it. There is probably a good reason it was designed that way.